# Difference between two lists that contain both integer and string values?

Tags: python, excel, string, int, set-difference

this is my first program in Python so thanks for any and all the help (Please see code below).

I am trying to get the difference between two lists that I have pulled from separate columns in seperate Excel files. The output when I run the Difference function is incorrect as it shows duplicates e.g. {'100' and 100} I suspect that this is because one list has integer & string values while the other list only has strings - therefore it includes both the integers and strings since they are "different".

I have tried to convert the list with integers and strings to all strings, and vice versa with little luck. While not ideal, I have also tried to remove format from the original Excel files hoping Python would import the absolute values with no assignment.

Can someone please help either change or suggest a better way to compare the absolute difference between two lists that have been generated from data in Excel files including different formats like integers and strings?

```
import openpyxl
import os
os.chdir('c:\\Users\\user\\PYTHON')

wbA = openpyxl.load_workbook('mms_rpg.xlsx') 
sheetA = wbA['Sheet1']
mylistA = []
for col in sheetA['J']:
    mylistA.append(col.value)


wbB = openpyxl.load_workbook('listings.xlsx')
sheetB = wbB['Sheet1']
mylistB = []
for col in sheetB['D']:
    mylistB.append(col.value)


#Get the Difference
WDP = set(mylistA)
EBAY = set(mylistB)

AnotB = EBAY.difference(WDP)
print(AnotB)
BnotA = WDP.difference(EBAY)
print(BnotA)
```

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Your data (mms_rpg.xlsx and listings.xlsx) are required in order to help.